# link working in browser but not in HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, android-networking, androidhttpclient

[image]

```
public class DPLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context context;


    DPLoader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String login_url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            try {

                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpurlconnection.setDoInput(true);
```

// here below i tried to read but not getting result

```
InputStream inputstream = httpurlconnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedreader.close();
                inputstream.close();
                httpurlconnection.disconnect();

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        return "null";

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       // Toast.makeText(context, ""+ usernameEt.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       Toast.makeText(context, ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```

image is the result toast which i get tried with ``` httpurlconnection.getErrorstream()`` and with ```httpurlconnection.getInputStream() i am getting null.
when i am opening link in browser it echo the result but not echo result in android httpurlconnection

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

Error says that you have no permission to access resource you are requesting. You need to pass login/password when making call with your HttpUrlConnection.

The reason why it is working in browser is most likely you are logged-in in browser already.

Comment: i am not logged in to this in browser but this link is working in browser to echo results but not working in adnroid

Comment: could you please tell me what is response code. You can get it as following: httpurlconnection.getResponseCode()